# Flip second dimension of tensor

Tags: python, theano

I want to flip order of elements in the second dimension of a tensor:

```
x = T.tensor3('x')
f = theano.function([x], ?)
print(f(x_data))
```

input:

```
x_data = [[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4]],
          [[5, 0, 0, 0], [0, 6, 0, 0], [0, 0, 7, 0], [0, 0, 0, 8]],
          [[9, 0, 0, 0], [0, 10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 11, 0], [0, 0, 0, 12]]
         ]
```

desired output:

```
x_data = [[[0, 0, 0, 4], [0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]],
          [[0, 0, 0, 8], [0, 0, 7, 0], [0, 6, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0]],
          [[0, 0, 0, 12], [0, 0, 11, 0], [0, 10, 0, 0], [9, 0, 0, 0]]
         ]
```

x_data[::-1] flips the overall second dimension (not desirable):

```
x_data = [[[ 11.   0.   0.   0.]
           [  0.  12.   0.   0.]
           [  0.   0.  13.   0.]
           [  0.   0.   0.  14.]]

           [[  5.   0.   0.   0.]
            [  0.   6.   0.   0.]
            [  0.   0.   7.   0.]
            [  0.   0.   0.   8.]]

           [[  1.   0.   0.   0.]
            [  0.   2.   0.   0.]
            [  0.   0.   3.   0.]
            [  0.   0.   0.   4.]]]
```

What is the simplest way to achieve the desired output ?

Comment: Your desired output has the second dimension flipped, not the third. Also, you're showing us a list of lists of lists, not a Theano tensor.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I have edited the question, I still think it's the 3rd dimension that needs to be flipped ?

Comment: If you were flipping the third dimension, your output would go `[[[0, 0, 0, 1], ...`, not `[[[0, 0, 0, 4], ...`.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, shape of tensor is (3, 4, 4) and I want the final 4th (right most / inner-most of shape) to be flipped, isn't it 3rd ?

Comment: You say you want that dimension flipped, but what you're showing for "desired output" has a completely different dimension flipped.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry it's indeed the 2nd dimension which needs to be flipped ...

Comment: *`x_data[::-1]` flips the overall second dimension (not desirable)* - why don't you do a reshape that moves the desired dimension to the position in which `x_data[::-1]` is now useful? I think it's also worthwhile pointing out that a lot of `theano` implementations throw extra dimensions in some really dodgy places and you should consider if you really need a tensor structure in the first instance

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Thank you ! Yes, reshaping  and then applying `x_data[::-1]` is a nice idea. I agree extra dimensions are not always needed (In my case I am working with language, so one need to represent sentence, words and then embeddings; and with mini-batch version I don't have an option other than using `tensors`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply flip the dimensions you want and use full slice on the dimension before that you don't want to be changed: x_data[::, ::-1]

```
import numpy as np
x = T.tensor3('x')
x_data = np.asarray([[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4]],
                 [[5, 0, 0, 0], [0, 6, 0, 0], [0, 0, 7, 0], [0, 0, 0, 8]],
                 [[9, 0, 0, 0], [0, 10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 11, 0], [0, 0, 0, 12]]
                 ], dtype=theano.config.floatX)
f = theano.function([x], x[::, ::-1])
print(f(x_data))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[line[::-1] for line in x_data ]
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to flip a dimension of a tensor not a simple list (I thought 'theano' tag was enough but it wasn't), sorry being unclear, kindly see the edited question.